# Hive Array<Struct<>> Insertion shows null

Tags: arrays, hadoop, struct, hive

I created a table temp that has array of struct

```
create table temp (regionkey smallint, name string, comment string, nations array<struct<n_nationkey:smallint,n_name:string,n_comment:string>>) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Then I loaded the data into the table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/Data Sets/region.csv' INTO TABLE temp;
```

Desired output when did

```
select * from temp;
```

is

```
4   EUROPE  Low sale Business Region [{"n_nationkey":22,"n_name":"Ryan","n_comment":"Reference the site"}]
```

But actual output is

```
4   EUROPE  Low sale Business Region    [{"n_nationkey":22,"n_name":null,"n_comment":null},{"n_nationkey":null,"n_name":null,"n_comment":null},{"n_nationkey":null,"n_name":null,"n_comment":null}]
```

DATA FILE

```
4|EUROPE|Low sale Business Region for Training4Exam.com|7,Bulgaria,Reference 
4|EUROPE|Low sale Business Region for HadoopExam.com|19,Belgium,Reference site 
4|EUROPE|Low sale Business Region for Training4Exam.com|22,Ryan,Reference site
```

This was my first exam with arrays and struct and I am blank on this.
Any help with be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: try to add some samples from your region.csv. the most probably reason is your data doesn't match the table layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`map keys terminated by ','`**

---

```
create external table temp 
(
    regionkey   smallint
   ,name        string
   ,comment     string
   ,nations     array<struct<n_nationkey:smallint,n_name:string,n_comment:string>>
) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '|' 
map keys terminated by ','
;
```

---

```
select * from temp
;
```

---

```
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| regionkey |  name  |                    comment                     |                                nations                                |
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         4 | EUROPE | Low sale Business Region for Training4Exam.com | [{"n_nationkey":7,"n_name":"Bulgaria","n_comment":"Reference "}]      |
|         4 | EUROPE | Low sale Business Region for HadoopExam.com    | [{"n_nationkey":19,"n_name":"Belgium","n_comment":"Reference site "}] |
|         4 | EUROPE | Low sale Business Region for Training4Exam.com | [{"n_nationkey":22,"n_name":"Ryan","n_comment":"Reference site"}]     |
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## FYI

> To be backward-compatible, initialize the first 3 separator to be the given values from the table properties.
>   The default number of separators is 8;
>   if only hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels is set, the number of separators is extended to 24;
>   if hive.serialization.extend.additional.nesting.levels is set, the number of separators is extended to 154.
>   @param tableProperties table properties to extract the user provided separators
>
> https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/lazy/LazySerDeParameters.java

Comment: Found 2 things on the way: **(1)** bug in serde.thrift https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/if/serde.thrift `const string COLLECTION_DELIM = "colelction.delim"` (note the typo in `colelction`) **(2)** The documentation of the delimiters is problematic. It is actually not fields, collection items and map keys but level 1,2, and 3 and there is even an additional level with default of ascii 4

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is very efficient & I liked it very much but cannot understand why collection items must be replaced by map keys (Seems there is a bug in Hive based on the description as he has suggested, I am not a pro in coding).

**However, this is the long version**

```
create table regiontemp(str string);
load data inpath '/user/cloudera/MohsenFiles/first_first.csv' into table regiontemp;
create external table region (r_regionkey smallint,
r_name      string,
r_comment   string,
r_nations   array<struct<n_nationkey:smallint,n_name:string,n_comment:string>>)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
collection items terminated by ','

insert overwrite table region
select split(str,'\\|')[0] r_regionkey,
split(str,'\\|')[1] r_name,
split(str,'\\|')[2] r_comment,
array(named_struct("n_nationkey",cast(split(split(str,'\\|')[3],",")[0] as smallint),
                             "n_name",split(split(str,'\\|')[3],",")[1] ,
                             "n_comment",split(split(str,'\\|')[3],",")[2] ))
from regiontemp ;
```

now in impala
INVALIDATE METADATA;

[image]

or in Hive ([Aggregation On Struct columns Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686496/aggregation-on-struct-columns-hive) again based on David's answer for another Q)
[image]